# Separate resources per package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

How can I separate my resource folder from my packages.

Right now I have an application which contains a server and a client software.
Some code is server-only, some code is client-only and there is shared code. Now apparently I **have** to put my Windows (FXML-Files) in the resources folder. How can I restrict this resources folder to be only in the server-package? I dont need my Server Window inside of my client.

Here a picture of the packages hierarchy on IntelliJ

[image: Picture of the hierarchy of my project]

I have one Run-Configuration for the Server and one Run-Configuration for the Client. (Or if you wish, I have one Server- and one Client Artifact.) I want to also have one Server Resources folder and one Client Resources folder.

Comment: Did you consider placing the shared code into its own package?

Comment: Isn't it in its own package? I don't know, in Eclipse I can create source folders, but in IntelliJ I can only create Modules...

Comment: I know what a Java package is and how to make a JAR out of it (manually) but I don't know your IDE so I guess I can't help much here.